# vector of template with two types

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I read related posts but still cannot figure it out. 
In my .h file, I defined a template class:

```
template <typename P, typename V>
class Item {
 public:
    P priority;
    V value;
    Item(P priority, V value): priority(priority), value(value){}
};
```

In my main function, I tried to make a vector of Items with specific type.

```
Item<int, string> Item1(18, "string 1");
Item<int, string> Item2(16, "string 2");
Item<int, string> Item3(12, "string 3");
Item<int, string> Item[3] = {Item1, Item2, Item3}
vector<Item<int, string> > Items(Item, Item + 3);
```

But I keep getting compile error saying:

```
expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
vector<Item<int, string> > Items(Item, Item + 9);
            ~~~^
```

Comment: You have called your array `Item` which is the same name as your class `Item`, causing the compiler to become confused.

Comment: You're also missing a semicolon after the array.

Comment: your code-style is bad, if you use `Item` as a class, please don't reuse the name `Item` for other uses. Also, if `Foo` is class name, object name should be `foo`. And also, your `Items` is an array, right? Let's see the declaration of this array. This is not compiler confusion, this is your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
template <typename P, typename V>
class Item
{
public:
    P priority;
    V value;
    Item(P priority, V value): priority(priority), value(value) {}
};
int main()
{
    Item<int, string> Item1(18, "string 1");
    Item<int, string> Item2(16, "string 2");
    Item<int, string> Item3(12, "string 3");
    Item<int, string> ItemL[3] = {Item1, Item2, Item3}; 
    vector<Item<int, string> > Items(ItemL, ItemL+3);
}
```

**You have several problem:**

1. Semicolon missing after `Item<int, string> Item[3] = {Item1, Item2, Item3}` line
2. In `Item<int, string> Item[3]` line Your class name `Item` and array of Item named `Item` ambiguous. So rename it other name, I rename it as `ItemL`